# Differentiating Between Different Bitmasks

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, physics

I am having trouble figuring out how to differentiate between different bitmasks.

I want this to happen:

```
 /*func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
if (spaceship1 collides with spaceship2) {
    print("contact between 1 and 2")
    }
if (spaceship1 collides with spaceship3) {
print("contact between 1 and 3")
    }
}
*/
```

Here's the code I have tried:

```
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask = enemy2Category) {
        print("contact between 1 and 2")
    }
}
```

Could I get some help?

EDIT: Here's the other code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

let enemy2Category: UInt32 = 1

let enemyCategory: UInt32 = 2

let enemy3Category: UInt32 = 3

var spaceship1: SKSpriteNode!
var spaceship2: SKSpriteNode!
var spaceship3: SKSpriteNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    spaceship1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship");
    spaceship1.setScale(CGFloat(0.1))
    spaceship1.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: (self.frame.height / 2));
    spaceship1.name = "spaceship1";


    spaceship1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: spaceship1.size.width / 2);
    spaceship1.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true // apply gravity, friction, and collision
    spaceship1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true;
    spaceship1.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    spaceship1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: spaceship1.size.width / 2);
    spaceship1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemy2Category
    spaceship1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = enemyCategory
    spaceship1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory

    spaceship2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship");
    spaceship2.setScale(CGFloat(0.1))
    spaceship2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: (spaceship1.position.y + 300));
    spaceship2.name = "spaceship2";

    spaceship2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: spaceship2.size.width / 2);
    spaceship2.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true // apply gravity, friction, and collision
    spaceship2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false;
    spaceship2.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    spaceship2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: spaceship2.size.width / 2);
    spaceship2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory
    spaceship2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = enemy2Category
    spaceship2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = enemy2Category

    spaceship3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship");
    spaceship3.setScale(CGFloat(0.1))
    spaceship3.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: (spaceship1.position.y + 300));
    spaceship3.name = "spaceship3";

    spaceship3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: spaceship2.size.width / 2);
    spaceship3.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true // apply gravity, friction, and collision
    spaceship3.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false;
    spaceship3.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    spaceship3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: spaceship2.size.width / 2);
    spaceship3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemy3Category
    spaceship3.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = enemy2Category | enemyCategory
    spaceship3.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = enemy2Category | enemyCategory


    addChild(spaceship1)

}


        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    addChild(spaceship3)
}

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        spaceship1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false;
}
```

}

I'm just trying to figure out how to detect which bitmasks come into contact with each other. Like if spaceship1 comes into contact with spaceship2, it prints yay, but if spaceship1 comes into contact with spaceship 3, it prints "wow"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a documentation article that tries to explain bit masks as used in Sprite-Kit collision and contacts, but I can no longer link to it. Try to find the 'Documentation' page, tag 'Sprite-Kit' then the 'Manipulating contactTest and collison bitmasks to enable/disable specific contact and collisions.' article under 'SKNode Collision'.

One obvious problem is this line :

```
let enemy3Category: UInt32 = 3
```

All bitmasks *have* to be thought of in binary, and in binary 3 is 11. This is the '1' bit and the '2' bit both being set to 1. **Category definitions** should only have 1 bit set to 1 which you ensure by using exact powers of 2 for your categories - 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc.

Objects in your scene that need to collide/contact should belong to only one category initially. For more advanced contacts and collisions, a sprite can belong to multiple categories.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an = in your if statement.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == enemy2Category) {
        print("contact between 1 and 2")
    }
}
```

Comment: @G.L. Do you have your contact bit masks setup correctly?  Post your code where you declare the bitmasks.

Comment: Yeah, collisions work, but I want it to do different things depending on which bitmask

Comment: I'll try to explain what I want better.

Comment: Let's say that I have 3 different bitmasks. I want bitmask #1 to print "a" when it touches bitmask #3. I want bitmask #2 to print "e" when it touches bitmask #1. How do I detect which bitmasks make contact with each other to differentiate the outcomes?

Answer (score 0):

This sets firstBody to the smaller bitmask And sets secondBody to the larger one

```
        var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
        var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB
        }else{
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }
```

Assuiming bitmask1 is smaller than 2 and 3.

```
        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == bitMask1 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == bitMask.bitmask3 {
            print("a")

        //If ball hits a pad, activate the pad
        }else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == bitMask1 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == bitMask.bitmask2 {
            print("e")
}
```